# Implementing a state machine with decorators

Tags: python, python-3.x, decorator, state-machine, python-decorators

While learning the concepts of decorators in python I came to the question if it is possible to use decorators to simulate a state machine.

Example:

```
from enum import Enum


class CoffeeMachine(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.state = CoffeeState.Initial

    #@Statemachine(shouldbe, willbe)
    @Statemachine(CoffeeState.Initial, CoffeeState.Grounding)
    def ground_beans(self):
        print("ground_beans")

    @Statemachine(CoffeeState.Grounding, CoffeeState.Heating)
    def heat_water(self):
        print("heat_water")

    @Statemachine(CoffeeState.Heating, CoffeeState.Pumping)
    def pump_water(self):
        print("pump_water")


class CoffeeState(Enum):
    Initial = 0
    Grounding = 1
    Heating = 2
    Pumping = 3
```

So all the statemachine does is to check if my current state is the requested one, if it is, it should call the underlying function and lastly it should set the state further.

How would you implement this?

Comment: Have you made any attempt to implement it? What happened? Where did you get stuck? Note that `CoffeeState` will have to be defined *before* you try to apply the `Statemachine`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can, provided your decorator makes an assumption about where the state is stored:

```
from functools import wraps


class StateMachineWrongState(Exception):
    def __init__(self, shouldbe, current):
        self.shouldbe = shouldbe
        self.current = current
        super().__init__((shouldbe, current))


def statemachine(shouldbe, willbe):
    def decorator(f):
        @wraps(f)
        def wrapper(self, *args, **kw):
            if self.state != shouldbe:
                raise StateMachineWrongState(shouldbe, self.state)
            try:
                return f(self, *args, **kw)
            finally:
                self.state = willbe
        return wrapper
    return decorator
```

The decorator expects to get `self` passed in; i.e. it should be applied to methods in a class. It then expects `self` to have a `state` attribute to track the state machine state.

Demo:

```
>>> cm = CoffeeMachine()
>>> cm.state
<CoffeeState.Initial: 0>
>>> cm.ground_beans()
ground_beans
>>> cm.state
<CoffeeState.Grounding: 1>
>>> cm.ground_beans()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 6, in wrapper
__main__.StateMachineWrongState: (<CoffeeState.Initial: 0>, <CoffeeState.Grounding: 1>)
>>> cm.heat_water()
heat_water
>>> cm.pump_water()
pump_water
>>> cm.state
<CoffeeState.Pumping: 3>
```